# Push an object into an object array then every property of object become undefined - Typescript

Tags: arrays, object, typescript, undefined, push

I tried to push an object into an object array as below (I want to use this way to update UI using Angular4):

In *CampgroundService.ts*

```
export class CampgroundDetail {
    campground: Campground;
    comments: Comment[];
}
```

In *CampgroundDetailComponent.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'campDetail',
    templateUrl: './app/components/campgrounds/campground.detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/campgrounds/campgrounds.component.css']
})

export class CampgroundDetailComponent {
    campDetail: CampgroundDetail = new CampgroundDetail();

    updateUI(comment: Comment) {
        console.log(comment);

        this.campDetail.comments.push(
        {
            id: comment.id,
            text: comment.text,
            campground_id: comment.campground_id,
            username: comment.username,
            user_id: comment.user_id
        });

        console.log(this.campDetail.comments);
    }
}
```

In *campground.detail.component.html*

```
<app-comment *ngIf="userdata" [comment]="selectedComment" (insertedComment)="updateUI($event)"></app-comment>
```

In *CommentFormComponent.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-comment',
    templateUrl: './app/components/campgrounds/comment.form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/campgrounds/campgrounds.component.css']
})

export class CommentFormComponent {
    @Output() insertedComment = new EventEmitter<Comment>();

    doSubmit() {
        this.comment.user_id = this.userdata.id;
        this.comment.username = this.userdata.username;
        this.comment.campground_id = this.campground_id;

        this.campgroundService.createComment(this.comment)
            .then(data => {
                this.campgroundService.getComment(data.comment_id)
                    .then(comment => this.insertedComment.emit(comment));
            }).catch(error => {
            if (error.status === 403) {
                this.userService.flush();
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

According to the first console log, the `comment` object is not null.

[image]

However, after pushing into the array every property of object became `undefined`.

[image: the value is undefined]

I tried to search on google as much as possible, but I still cannot find any solution. What am I missing? I will appreciate if anyone would give me any suggestion.

Comment: How are you passing the `comment` object to `updateUI`? It is possible that `comment` is just an empty object without any of the properties you are using.

Comment: Hi, the comment object is not empty (I updated the screenshot).

Comment: How are you passing it to `updateUI`? Post that as well. Does it involve anything asynchronous?

Comment: yeah, I guess it involves in asynchronous. In `CommentFormComponent.ts`, I get the `comment` object back as a `@Output` object for `CampgroundDetailComponent.ts`. Do you think is this a problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your comment object is probably not filled by the time `updateUI` is executed. Verify this by `JSON.stringify`ing your object before logging to log its current state: `console.log(JSON.stringify(comment))`

Comment: I got this in the console `{"comment":{"id":38,"username":"bluegray","user_id":1,"text":"I love here~","campground_id":5}}`. It's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally. I modified *CampgroundService.ts*

```
export class CampgroundDetail {
    campground: Campground;
    comments: any[];
}
```

and modified *CampgroundDetailComponent.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'campDetail',
    templateUrl: './app/components/campgrounds/campground.detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app/components/campgrounds/campgrounds.component.css']
})

export class CampgroundDetailComponent {
    campDetail: CampgroundDetail = new CampgroundDetail();

    updateUI(comment: Comment) {
        let tempComment = comment['comment'];
        this.campDetail.comments.push(tempComment);
    }
}
```

It works now.